# Python. setup.py изменяет файл скрипта?

Tags: python, setup

Добрый день!
Создал небольшой скрипт, выложил на github, теперь хочу добавить на pypi.python.org, но есть проблема. В основном файле, в первой строке есть объявление:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
```

Но при установке через pip в /usr/local/bin создаётся файл, первая строчка которого:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

При добавлении изменений в оригинальный файл и повторной установке изменения сохраняются, но первая строчка всё равно без "3", а скрипт работает только с 3-ей версией :(

Как быть?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил рассказать как справился с проблемой. Всё дело в том, что шла установка с pip для python 2.7. Так как pip для python 3 пока ещё не особо распространён, то исправил всё при помощи добавления э... короче теперь можно использовать как с python 2, так и с 3. Вот кусок кода:

```
try:
    from urllib.request import urlopen
except:
    from urllib import urlopen
```